# link error when change configuration from Debug to Release

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Hi 
I have project In VC++ 2008 
this project compile in debug mode  without error
but when I try to build it in release mode I get below linking erorr.

```
1>Linking...
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __heap_alloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __recalloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(recalloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbgheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __msize already defined in LIBCMT.lib(msize.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(malloc.obj) : error LNK2005: _V6_HeapAlloc already defined in LIBCMT.lib(malloc.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(dbghook.obj) : error LNK2005: __crt_debugger_hook already defined in LIBCMT.lib(dbghook.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: ___sbh_pHeaderDefer already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_sbh_threshold already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_sbh_threshold already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __set_amblksiz already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)
1>LIBCMTD.lib(sbheap.obj) : error LNK2005: __get_amblksiz already defined in LIBCMT.lib(sbheap.obj)......
```

how I can fix it?
thanks.

Answer (score 24):

You're mixing VS runtimes - Make sure the "Project Properties/C++/Code Generation/Run-time Library" setting is the same for your project and all libraries you link to.

Comment: in all them Multi-threaded (/MT) when this configured to release.is some other linking that I use ony compiled libs and link to them by hear files

Comment: Well, not *exactly* the same, e.g. if debug is using /MTd then release should use /MT, etc. but debug should not use /MT.

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: No, one of them uses `/MTd` - that's what creates the dependency on `LIBCMTD`. You could also check to see that `NDEBUG` and **not** `_DEBUG` is defined for the release build.

Comment: @erik NDEBUG this ok but if I have a lib file that compiled in debug this be problem?

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: Yes. Compile this as release as well.

Comment: @herzl shemuelian : Yes, that is absolutely the problem. Link your debug build to debug libraries and your release build to release libraries.

Comment: I haven't cpp files I have only headr and binary libs. exist any solution?.

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: Usually you get both a debug and a release build of such libs - Change your projects linker inputs for release mode to use the release lib.

Comment: already i see lib and libd but i can't find where my configuration link to the libd folder that I can change it ot lib. for small test I change libd to libd1 but I have only warnnig errors.

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: "Project Properties, Linker, General, Additional Library Directories" and "Project Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies"

Comment: @Erik: this for exe output project.what about lib output project?

Comment: @herzl shemuelian: You don't need to specify dependencies for static library outputs - You specify these when you build an EXE or DLL.

Comment: Vielen danke :D, thanks for this solution. But could you say me how can I learn when I need to change "Project Properties/C++/Code Generation/Run-time Library" to MTd for debug and MT for release and when I need not do that? I'm pretty naive in C++ :(. @ildjarn

Comment: Whew. This saved me some time. I was dealing with a non-debug file that was only compiled in release mode, so I had to set the debug build to non-debug.

Comment: @Erik, you just saved me. Really NDEBUG and not _DEBUG should be defined!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem as you. Reason of this problem is that Linker include a lot of libraries that you dont see (for example you will include **windows.h**, it includes **windef.h** and so on...). And because these files are not idiot-proof written (`#ifndef` is missing) linker will try to `#define` same thing more times than once - problem.

My solution was setting this field:
Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Ignore specific library

to "**libcmt.lib**"

With this your linker will ignore **also in release configuration** that problematic library that is included by default and everything should work.. :-)

Have a nice day.. :-)

P.S. If you want to avoid these linker misunderstandings, keep configuring project not in debug or release configuration, but in "All configuration". This option is on left upper corner of project configuration.

Comment: I would add `LIBCMTD.lib` to the ignore list since you are trying build a release version

Answer (score 2):

You are linking a .obj or .lib file that was compiled in the Debug configuration.  Best thing to do is to ensure that file is built in the Release mode as well.  Second best is to tell the linker to ignore the request to link to libcmtd.lib.  Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Ignore Specific Library = libcmtd.lib.  But only do this if you can't get the Release build of a .lib after trying mightily.

Comment: I used ignore libcmtd.lib but I see other link errors:
>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>fifi++.lib(Field.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>fifi++.lib(Int32Field.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW

Comment: The .lib actually uses debugging features.  You are *really* going to have to rebuild it, the shortcut won't work.

Answer (score 1):

you can delete preprocessor definition "DEBUG" to solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

I ran into to similar problem and it was all to do with whether libraries you include build with right end state. If you build a program in release mode and pointed to *.lib files that compiled in debug mode. its going to give you symbol miss match errors. Specially if your program build fines in debug mode or vise versa.

This might not exactly what your problem is but good information for someone who ran into same thing as i did.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have defined all the link information in the "Debug" configuration. Which means you need to either redefine it for "Release" or move it to the "All Configurations" so its shared.