# C++ Vector manipulation errors

Tags: c++, vector

I am currently using a vector in my program, and I am getting some strange errors, which appeared only after I started using the  class.

The errors are:

```
1>MyCloth.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW referenced in function "public: unsigned int & __thiscall std::vector<unsigned int,class std::allocator<unsigned int> >::operator[](unsigned int)" (??A?$vector@IV?$allocator@I@std@@@std@@QAEAAII@Z)
1>libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CrtDbgReportW
1>D:\Licenta\Project\IOPBTS\Debug\IOPBTS.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

And my code is:

in the header file:

```
#undef vector
#include <vector>

void findPieceVertices(NxU32 selectedVertex); 
bool checkVertexExistsInClothPieceElements(int vertex);
void findVertexTriangles(NxU32 vertex);
std::vector<NxU32> clothPieceElements;
```

In the cpp file:

```
bool MyCloth::checkVertexExistsInClothPieceElements(int vertex)
{
for(int i=0;i<clothPieceElements.size();i++)
    if(clothPieceElements[i]==vertex)
        return true;
return false;
}

void MyCloth::findVertexTriangles(NxU32 vertex)
{
NxMeshData data = mCloth->getMeshData();
NxU32* vertices = (NxU32*)data.indicesBegin;
NxU32 aux = 0;

for(int i=0;i<(mInitNumVertices-1)*3;i+=3)
{
    if(*vertices == vertex || *(vertices+1) == vertex || *(vertices+2) == vertex)
    {
        if(!checkVertexExistsInClothPieceElements(*vertices))
            clothPieceElements.push_back(*vertices);
        if(!checkVertexExistsInClothPieceElements(*(vertices+1)))
            clothPieceElements.push_back(*(vertices+1));
        if(!checkVertexExistsInClothPieceElements(*(vertices+2)))
            clothPieceElements.push_back(*(vertices+2));
    }
    vertices = vertices + 3;
}
```

}

```
void MyCloth::findPieceVertices(NxU32 selectedVertex)
{
clothPieceElements.push_back(selectedVertex);
int i=0;
while(i<clothPieceElements.size())
{
    findVertexTriangles(clothPieceElements[i]);
    i++;
}

}
```

What am I doing wrong? I found something on the internet, which said that the files I use were compiled in release mode and I should do that too. The problem is, if I compile in release mode these errors go away, but My program fails to find a very important non-C library, which is pointed to by a path added in the VCC Directories->Include directories.

Does anyone know why this error occurs?Or what it means

Edit: also, could anyone tell me the difference between building in debug or release mode?

Comment: By default release does a lot more optimization, so the program is smaller and faster but harder to debug. I think debug also sets stuff to 0xCECECE and breaks at overflowing pointers instead of crashing by always allocating a byte more. To have the lib in release mode in the Proj Settings change the debug to release and then set the includes there too. AFAIK all libs should work in release and debug though.

Comment: I think you don't link to the correct runtime library: a debug one for the Debug configuration (some assertions needs CrtDbgReport)

Comment: Shouldn't linking to release in debug mode always work? I would think it just wouldn't debug as nicely.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, I am using a physics engine and I just took the lib files that they provided, but you might be right, and I might have takes the debug version, thus it doesn't work in release version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I solved it. The problem was in C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library. I was using /MT, when I needed to use /MTd (debug). It works now. I only excluded from the project the LIBCD library, I am using GLUI and otherwise the project won't work

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you made a mess with CRT libraries. There are two main differences between Debug and Release builds:

- Different CRT libraries are used
- Different optimizations to the code are done

Both are related to your question. First, [check this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530417/link-error-when-change-configuration-from-debug-to-release#comment6292104_5530744). It seems like you are missing `libcmtd.lib` from your link line. Check that you're not excluding important libraries like this from the link under Linker -> Input option.

The function `__CrtDbgReportW` is related to some runtime checks that the `vector::operator[]` is performing in Debug build. Since these checks are disabled in Release build, you don't have this error in Release.

Also make sure you are using the proper version of CRT under C/C++ -> Code generation option. You should have a debug version (dynamic or static) for Debug configuration and a release version for Release configuration.

This is a tricky issue to get through without any experience. If you have the possibility, I would recommend to create a new project from the default template and add all your files to this new project to make sure all the settings are set right by default.